# Center image in enumitem environment

Tags: floats, positioning, enumitem

In the enumitem environment at the secondary level of itemization, I want my figure to be centered relative to the text that is indented. How do I do this?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}
\item Lorem ipsum
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.7]{Rectangle.pdf}
 \end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Typeset document looks like this:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 7):

The purpose of the `figure` environment is to mark the region as a float that may be inserted in another part of the docuemnt, so it is not "in" the list, it would look very strange indented if it was added on a different page.

As you want the image to be part of the list text then do not use `figure`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}
\item Lorem ipsum
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 


\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.7]{example-image}
 \end{center}

\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was simple!